# Pandas: Perform a Formula Calculation on Different Columns then Sum All of It

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have set of data as follow

```
import pandas as pd 
dataset = [['01-01-2015', 234, '25-05-2017', 633, '03-06-2016', 935, '30-10-2019', 673, '16-12-2020', 825, '06-07-2019']]
ds = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns = ['Start_Date', 'A', 'End_Date_A', 'B', 'End_Date_B', 'C', 'End_Date_C', 
                                      'D', 'End_Date_D', 'E', 'End_Date_E'])

Output:
    Start_Date  A   End_Date_A  B   End_Date_B  C   End_Date_C  D   End_Date_D  E   End_Date_E
0   01-01-2015  234 25-05-2017  633 03-06-2016  935 30-10-2019  673 16-12-2020  825 06-07-2019
```

Then, I want to perform a calculation whereby for every end date of letter need to be minus with the `Start_Date`, then divide with 365 to get duration in years. Then the duration of each letter need to be use as a '*power of*' of the value of their letter, respectively. Then the result of each letter need to be sum up to get the total.

Is there a way to perform a loop of this calculation?

Comment: Yes there is, but is Pandas compulsory? You can easily write a function in vanilla Python to do this. If Pandas is a must, changing the format of dataframe would make the problem a lot easier.

Comment: @lpounng not necessarily using Pandas. Other function in Python also can as long as it will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parser. I'm assuming the data looks as you have posted.

For this example, I'm using `dateutil` - but you can use any other in a similar way.

```py
import pandas as pd
dataset = [['01-01-2015', 234, '25-05-2017', 633, '03-06-2016', 935, '30-10-2019', 673, '16-12-2020', 825, '06-07-2019']]
ds = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns = ['Start_Date', 'A', 'End_Date_A', 'B', 'End_Date_B', 'C', 'End_Date_C',
                                      'D', 'End_Date_D', 'E', 'End_Date_E'])


from dateutil import parser
import math

letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
start_date = parser.parse(ds["Start_Date"][0])
total = 0

for letter in letters:
    end_date = parser.parse(ds["End_Date_" + letter][0])
    years = (end_date - start_date).days / 365
    power = math.pow(int(ds[letter][0]), years)
    total+= power
    print(letter, ":",power)
    
print("total: ", total)
```

I just printed the result, but you can play with the concept to do what you actually need.

Comment: @l M How about if the header is in date format i.e Jun2022, Jul2022, Aug2022. Can we do in parser too?

Comment: @l M I've tried and it's exactly as what I need. However, I require the result to be show in a dataframe such as `ds['Overall'] = total`. But then, I get same total for the other row as well. Does `parser` can be used with dataframe more than 1 rows?

Comment: A simple, but not a great solution would be to just iterate over all the rows and perform the operation I provided - save the results and then insert them.

Answer (score 0):

With Pandas, I would organize the data as follows:

| End_date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 25-05-2017 | 234 |
| 03-06-2016 | 633 |
| 30-10-2019 | 935 |
| 16-12-2020 | 673 |
| 06-07-2019 | 825 |

You may want to set the letters 'A' etc. as index or an extra column, though not strictly required. There is no need to put the `Start_Date` in dataframe if it is constant.

Assume that all dates are `date` object. Now, subtract the end date by start date and divide by 365:

```
df['Duration'] = (df['End_date'] - Start_Date).dt.days / 365
```

Do the 'Power of' row-wise:

```
df['Value_powered'] = df['Value'] ** df['Duration']
```

Finally, sum:

```
result = df['Value_powered'].sum()
```